# SpringData CrudRepository only reads (it doesn't save, update or delete)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have following issue. I would like to use Spring Data CrudRepository with Hibernate 5 in my application. As DB I use MySQL version 5.7.21.
I think I configured it wrongly, because when I run my application I am able to read from DB only. When i use any other CrudRepository method eg. save() 
there is no reaction. In Hibernate logs i see only read Select statement (there should be insert statement but it seems that hibernate doesn't create it).

Example log when I use save(animal) method LOG:

```
Hibernate: /* load com.entity.Animal */ select animal0_.animal_id as animal_i1_0_0_, animal0_.name as name2_0_0_, animal0_.type as type3_0_0_ from animal animal0_ where animal0_.animal_id=?
```

It is only issue with SpringData CrudRepository, because when i configure application to use only Hibernate i can read and write to DB using 
this method:

```
public void save(Animal animal) {
          sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(animal);
       }
```

My question is: What I did wrong with configuration? I would like to be able to save my Entity to DB.

I will be very thankful for any suggestion or links.

My Configuration:
pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>train</groupId>
    <artifactId>train</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>train Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>train</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

AppConfig.java

```
package com.configuration;


import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import com.entity.Animal;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com")
@ComponentScan("com")
public class AppConfig{

    // Configuration Beans
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", false);
         hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
         hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", true);

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
        sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(Animal.class);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name="transactionManager")
     public PlatformTransactionManager txManager(){
     JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(
             entityManagerFactory(dataSource()).getObject());
     return jpaTransactionManager;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projekt?useSSL=false");
        dataSource.setUsername("Programowanie@localhost");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");

        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setPrepareConnection(true);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.generate_statistics", false);
         hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
         hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", true);
         factory.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);
        return factory;
    }

}
```

Entity: Animal.java

```
package com.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="animal")
public class Animal {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="animal_id", insertable=true)
    private Long animalId;

    @Column(name="name", insertable=true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="type", insertable=true)
    private String type;

    public Long getAnimalId() {
        return animalId;
    }

    public void setAnimalId(Long animalId) {
        this.animalId = animalId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

AnimalController.java

```
package com;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.entity.Animal;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class AnimalController {
    @Autowired private AnimalService animalService;
    public AnimalController() {

    }
    public AnimalController(AnimalService animalService) {
        this.animalService = animalService;
    }
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/animal/{id}")
    public Animal getGreeting(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return animalService.getAnimal(id);
    }


    @PostMapping("/animal")
    public void saveGreeting(@RequestBody Animal animal) {
        animalService.saveAnimal(animal);
    }

}
```

AnimalService.java

```
package com;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.entity.Animal;

@Service
public class AnimalService {

    @Autowired
    private AnimalRepository animalRepository;

    public Animal saveAnimal(Animal animal) {
        return animalRepository.save(animal);
    }

    public Animal getAnimal(Long id) {
        return animalRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
}
```

AnimalRepository.java

```
package com;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.entity.Animal;

@Repository
@Transactional
public interface AnimalRepository extends CrudRepository<Animal, Long> {

}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code and clearly not a minimal example.

Comment: Transactional should be on the implementation class, not on the interface. And it should annotate your service or even your controller.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Transactional` annotation on the repository interface does not help much. It needs to get somewhere where these methods are actually called, in your case that would be `AnimalService`. You can put them either on each method or the class itself. Annotating your controller may also work; dependening on the setup, I have seen it conflict with `@Controller` in the old times, but did not check your code here.

There is, however, one case where this annotation does something useful on the interfacse: With `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` you change the default for that option for each method in the interface, and can set it to `false` only the methods that really change something. This, however, is an optimization that should come later.

You also use `@Repository` on the repository interface. This has no additional effect. It triggers exceptions translation, but Spring Data reposiories already do that anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use @Transactional(readOnly = false), but it didn't work. I changed database to PostgreSQL and i changed only DB configuration. It "solved" my issue.